# Haskell: the index of a maximum element in an Array

Tags: arrays, haskell, indexing, max

Given an `Array`, I need to compute the index of the maximum element (which is assumed to be unique).

My current attempt is:

```
maxIndex' :: (Ix i, Ord a) => Array i a -> [i] -> i -> a -> i -> a -> i
maxIndex' arr ids index element maxIndex maxElement
  | length ids == 1 && element > maxElement = index
  | length ids == 1 && element <= maxElement = maxIndex
  | element > maxElement = maxIndex' arr (tail ids) (head ids) (arr ! head ids) index element
  | otherwise = maxIndex' arr (tail ids) (head ids) (arr ! head ids) maxIndex maxElement

maxIndex :: (Ix i, Ord a) => Array i a -> i
maxIndex arr = maxIndex' arr (tail (indices arr)) firstIndex firstMaximum firstIndex firstMaximum
  where
    firstIndex = head (indices arr)
    firstMaximum = arr ! firstIndex
```

The current implementation, however, is incorrect:

```
print (maxIndex (array (False,True) [(False,54),(True,104)])) -- Prints False.
print (maxIndex (array (False,True) [(True,104),(False,54)])) -- Prints False.
```

So, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `maxIndex` function is very complicated, and honestly I don't understand what you are doing. In general, If you are doing a lot of `head`, `tail` and explicit recursion something has gone already wrong. The easiest approach is to transform the array in a linked list of pairs `(index, element)`, compare them by the second element of the pair, and get the first one (the `index`)

```
import Data.Array
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (maximumBy)

-- Notice maximumBy is partial
maxIndex = fst . maximumBy (compare `on` snd) . assocs 
--         |     |                              |- the list of (index, array_element)
--         |     |- maximum using a custom comparision function. In this case, compare on second element in the tuple
--         |- get the first element of the tuple
main = do  
  let arr = array (False,True) [(False,54),(True,104)]
  print $ maxIndex arr
```

Comment: You might also like [`comparing`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.18.0.0/docs/Data-Ord.html#v:comparing) (`= on compare`).

Answer (score 0):

Found that meets my experience level:

```
maxIndex :: (Ix i, Ord a) => Array i a -> i
maxIndex arr = fst (sortBy (\(_,a) (_,b) -> compare b a) (assocs arr) !! 0)
```

Comment: Nice you found a different solution. Notice `(\(_,a) (_,b) -> compare b a)` is the same as `compare \`on\` snd`. The `on` combinator is a little it weird, but In general functions ending in `By` (like `sortBy`, `maximumBy`, etc...) interact very well with it. Now, my approach was to use `maximumBy` instead of sorting and then take the first, which is slower I think. But, yes this solution and mine are very similar indeed

Comment: @lsmor I think it's actually ```flip (compare `on` snd)```!

Comment: @DanielWagner Indeed!!